# Can I make the preview pane of Expression Web 4 honor <?php include ... ?> directives?

Tags: php, expression-web

I have a website that uses a global `header.inc` file, containing the header I want on top of every HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de-at" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="standard.css.php" />
  ...etc...
```

Hence, the pages themselves look like this:

```
<?php include "header.inc"; ?>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* additional style sheets for only this page */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  ...
```

Obviously, Expression Web complains about the unopened `</head>` tag and ignores the stuff present in the header file (e.g., the stylesheet), which makes the preview pane rather useless.

Since EW4 is supposed to "work nicely" with PHP, is there some way to make the preview pane honor `include`s? I've told EW where it can find the `php-cgi.exe`, so in the *browser preview* everything works nicely.

Comment: Why do you care what EW thinks?

Comment: I'm afraid not. EW4 does not evaluate PHP so it has no way of completing the DOM. I suggest switching to another tool like VS.php for Visual Studio.

Comment: @DainisAbols: `..., which makes the preview pane rather useless.`  I like the preview pane. I'd like to use it.